# Flutter - Remove padding from Circular Elevated Button

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I have a simple view with a Column and two Rows, the second row has a list of circular buttons, which I would like to be aligned with the beginning of the first row.
Unfortunately, probably because of the CircularBorder I can't do it... Any idea how to make it work?

```
    Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      bottom: 12.0,
                      top: 20.0,
                    ),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: Text("Select preferred options",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Color(0XFF8E8E8E),
                            fontSize: 15.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                          )),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      ...TransportModes.publicTransport.options.map(
                        (e) => Container(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                color: Colors.red,
                                child: ElevatedButton(
                                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                    shape: const CircleBorder(),
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                                    primary: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.tertiary,
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () {},
                                  child: ImageIcon(
                                    AssetImage(iconPath),
                                    size: 20.0,
                                    color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onTertiary,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                text,
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                  color: Color(0XFF8E8E8E),
                                  fontSize: 13.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

I would like the first circle to start aligned with the text above...

Comment: use crossAxisAlignment : Start into the Column widget under the row widget column

Answer (score 0):

The space around the circle is caused by `minimumSize:` property in the default style of elevated button.

Add `minimumSize: Size(40, 40)` or (your preferred height and width) inside  `style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom()`.